# Linux terminal asks to show 1080 possibilities after using "then"

Tags: terminal

I wrote a simple code:

```
if[ a=1  ]
then
     Echo "Hello"
else
     Echo "No hello"
fi
```

And after `then` it displayed me 1080 commands. :Can you help me?

Comment: What programming language is this, on what platform? What is the 'it' that showed you something? What kind of help would you like to receive? What is your specific question?

Comment: Its LXTERMINAL on rasberry pi, by it I meant the terminal, I would like to know what am I doing wrong.The question is what am I doeing wrong.

Comment: Why do you assume you're doing something wrong? Apparently there are 1080 commands to show you.